# ListView in VB.NET (VS 2010)

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview

I am trying to display sql database table data in a list view in my vb application. I have used the following code

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim itemcoll(100) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
    Me.ListView1.GridLines = True
    conn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=AYYAGARI-PC\WINCC;Initial Catalog=anand;Integrated Security=True")
    conn.Open()
    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    strQ = "SELECT * FROM [anand].[dbo].[WINCC] ORDER BY [dateandtime]"
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
    da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Table")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    ' adding the columns in ListView
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString())
    Next
    'Now adding the Items in Listview
    Try
        Call Timer1_Tick(sender, e)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    For Each i As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
        ListView1.Items.Remove(i)
    Next
    Try
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
            Next
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
            Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The problem with the above code is that whenever i update the table data in sql (inserting or deleting data), the same doesnt get updated in list view. Kindly help me out with this.

Comment: Then are you sure the data you insert or update already save to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
    Me.ListView1.GridLines = True
    conn = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=AYYAGARI-PC\WINCC;Initial Catalog=anand;Integrated Security=True")
    conn.Open()
    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    strQ = "SELECT * FROM [anand].[dbo].[WINCC] ORDER BY [dateandtime]"
    cmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
    da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Table")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    ' adding the columns in ListView
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        Me.ListView1.Columns.Add(ds.Tables(0).Columns(i).ColumnName.ToString())
    Next
    'Now adding the Items in Listview
    Try
        Call Timer1_Tick(sender, e)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Try to add this code again to your button which made insert or update.

**UPDATE**

I give you another tips, that wont make your code so long and wasted memory or capacity..

Try to insert all the code to new sub, e.g :

```
    private sub mycode
    msgbox("Hello World")
    end sub >> This code won't work when you debug, cause it just like a stored code, so need to be called to make it work

Private sub Form_load......  > E.g this is your form load code
call mycode  >> Called the code above
end sub >> when you debug, your form will auto called the mycode
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer then.
I also give you another tip to make your code not be so long,,

Comment: It is already marked as an answer right??
How can i make this code shorter?
I have one more query, suppose there are 10 items in my list box and if i click on the 5th Item, all the 5th item related data should get moved into variables. How can this be done? Kindly help

Comment: I found a Solution for that too.

 Try
            Dim a = ListView1.Items(ListView1.FocusedItem.Index).SubItems(0).Text
            MessageBox.Show(a)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

Comment: i just want to tape it. you need to check the V for mark as answer